# Activity calling RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH is not called

Tags: java, android

I implemented an activity that performs Speech Recognition that works pretty well when invoked directly. When I call it from within a Service, it's not called at all. I see this behaviour on Android 4.x and upper.

This is how I call it:

```
Intent voiceRecognitionIntent = new Intent(this,VoiceRecognitionActivity.class);
        voiceRecognitionIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(voiceRecognitionIntent);
```

and this is the actual Activity code:

```
    public class VoiceRecognitionActivity extends CustomRecognitionListener {
        WiredLog  log = new WiredLog(this.getClass().getName());

        private void sameOldStory(){

            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            if (null == context){
                log.debug("RECOGNIZE:::CONTEXT IS NULL");
            } else {
                log.debug("RECOGNIZE:::CONTEXT IS NOT NULL");
            }

            SpeechRecognizer sr = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(context);

            log.debug("------------------------------------");
            if (sr.isRecognitionAvailable(context)){
                log.debug("RECOGNIZE:::RECOGNITION AVAILABLE");
            } else {
                log.debug("RECOGNIZE:::RECOGNITION IS _NOT_ AVAILABLE");
            }
            log.debug("------------------------------------");

            log.debug("instanciated SpeechRecognizer");
            CustomRecognitionListener listener = new CustomRecognitionListener();
            log.debug("instanciated CustomRecognitionListener");
            listener.setContext(context);

            sr.setRecognitionListener(this);

            Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "RICONOSCIMI::");

            sr.startListening(intent);

            log.debug("AFTER launching startListening");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            sameOldStory();

        }


        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            sameOldStory();
        }

         public void onResults(Bundle results) {
             log.debug("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^");
             log.debug("onResults");
             ArrayList strlist = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
             for (int i = 0; i < strlist.size();i++ ) {
              log.debug(  "result=" + strlist.get(i));
              String riga = "" + strlist.get(i);

              try{
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                          riga, 
                          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }catch(Exception e){
                  log.error("Toasting:"+e);
              }
             }
             log.debug("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^");
            }
```

Any hints ?

Comment: Do you have any logcat output that would show what is happening when your code runs?

Comment: I/Timeline(23878): Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:nd.vr time:202025034
E/PersonaManagerService( 1004): inState():  stateMachine is null !!
I/PersonaManagerService( 1004): Failed to execute isKioskModeEnabled. java.lang.SecurityException: You need MANAGE_USERS permission to: query user
I/ActivityManager( 1004): do not start freezing screen for locked container getKeyguardshowstate = false
W/ActivityManager( 1004): userId = 0, bbcId = -10000
W/ActivityManager( 1004): NORMAL SET : dst_category = 1023, src_allowCategory = 0,501-1023

Comment: Put that logcat output into the question and not as comment. Format it so that it is better readable. It is part of your problem. Also, add the code that is mentioned in this output (`PersonaManagerService`, the interesting lines).

Comment: PersonaManagerService is not in my own code